# FastAPI workers with shared data across functions called in an aggregate function

Tags: python, pandas, caching, redis, fastapi

I have a FastAPI app that has a route that can dynamically (more or less) call the functions that I need to call. That function also loads the data needed for those functions to run. The data that is loaded and passed to each function is the same and thee functions then pick the data they need to use.

This system works good enough for my liking for a one of call to that route. The issue comes when calling this from an aggregate route which calls this end point 8 times (re-loading the data on every request.. The time to load the data adds up!)

A working solution was to have a dict that acted as a sort of session object that would either return the already loaded data or load it if it wasn't already loaded. While working I'm not exactly confident in the approach seeing as it would also have to re-load the data for every worker..

I've tried the same approach as above but utilising Redis, issue is the data the I need to load is Pandas DataFrames so there's a lot of pickling and unpicking of large data sets which is very time intensive so lands me back at square one..

Im pretty new to FastAPI and uvicorn so Im a bit stuck as to where to go next or how to solve this issue.

Any help/adive would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into something like `multiprocessing.shared_memory`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html

Comment: Hmm.. very interesting! I shall take a look at that, thanks a lot